# Exit Application - Windows Phone Certification

Tags: windows-phone-7

This is a code to exit the application.

```
if (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
{
            while (NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry() != null)
            {
                NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
            }
}
```

Can anybody tell me if it is permitted from Windows Phone Certification Requirements perspective????

Answer (score 3):

You should not disrupt the normal application flow by doing this. The user expects to close the application either by hitting the back button, or the Windows key. The user might also expect to resume the application work via Fast App Switching.

Besides, your method won't exit the application because at one point you will hit the main page, where it can't go back. After that, back entry removal will not be possible.

Bottom line: **don't do this.**

A good explanation from Peter Torr is available [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/01/exiting-a-windows-phone-application.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

In one of my application, my task was to exit when a user reset his/her account. The application is in the store so there is no problem. i'm sure you can achieve exit with this code and it will be ok:

```
var g = new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game();
                    g.Exit();
```

just add reference to `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game`

[look at this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184840%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

> **5.1.2 - App closure**

```
The app must handle exceptions raised by the any of the managed or native System API 
and not close unexpectedly. During the certification process, the app is monitored 
for unexpected closure. An app that closes unexpectedly fails certification. The app
must continue to run and remain responsive to user input after the exception is
handled.
```

For example you just need a message, so **THE EXIT** will be expected.